# AccessTokens returned for Active Directory are different between sample projects

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've been experimenting with Azure Active Directory access for Java using two sample projects:

1) https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java which builds a stand-alone war using OAuth tokens for security, and

2) https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample for spring-boot embeded containers

I've come across quite a difference in the way the APIs can be used, that I can't understand.

In both cases, I get an OAuth token for AD by logging in with my Azure credentials. 
In the Http response, I get an authorizationCode of the form:

> AQABAAIAAAD.....

Then using the following URL as an authContext:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}

I get a AuthenticationResult by making the following call:

```
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, redirectUri, credential, null);
```

in the Adal4j project (1), the AuthenticationResult's AccessToken is of the form:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6I...

Which I can use as a Bearer token in an HTTP call to retrieve the user's profile picture via https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6

whereas in the SpringBoot AD example, the AccessToken returned from exactly the same call is of the form:

> AQABAAAAAADXzZ3ifr-GRbDT....

and If I use that in exactly the same way to try to retrieve the user's profile pic, I get a 401 Unauthorized response

What's the reason for the difference in the form and use of these AccessTokens?

Comment: Maybe the second token is Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Try looking at these tokens in decoded format using tools like https://jwt.io or https://jwt.ms and it might shed some more light on the differences..

Comment: Do you have any update about this SO thread?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the reason for the difference in the form and use of these AccessTokens?

I assume that you got the access token is **authorization_code** not the bearer token.

As Rohit Saigal mentioned that you could use [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/) or [JWT.MS](https://jwt.ms/) to check that.

If we want to get the access token for Azure AD graph we could use the follow code to do that.

```
public String index(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
...
DefaultOidcUser user = (DefaultOidcUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
String accessToken = user.getIdToken().getTokenValue(); 
...
}
```

Then we could use the access token to access the Azure AD graph api if you have assiged corrosponding permission.